# Unique values and frequencies across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, array-formulas

I am using Office 365 / Microsoft Forms to collect information into an Excel workbook. The number for sheets (and forms) can increase over time. Hence I have bookmarked these sheets by adding a sheet "Start" to the left of these sheets and sheet "Stop" to the right.
[image]

The relevant piece of information collected on the sheets is the email address of the respondents, which arrives in column A (all sheets have the same structure).
[image]

What I would like to do is to have a "Summary" sheet after the "Stop" sheet, in which I have a dynamic list of all the unique emails across all sheets between "Start" and "Stop" and their frequencies in columns A and B respectively.

I reckon that once I have a list of emails, I could calculate the frequency of each via a `COUNTIF` across sheets - though that is less than ideal as the list would grow over time, so this solution would require copying over the formula to new rows ever so often. But what I am really struggling with is how to get the list of all unique values from column A of all the sheets between "Start" and "Stop"?

Comment: There is a trick here for getting a list of tabs but it entails macro-enabling your sheet https://www.journalofaccountancy.com/issues/2018/nov/create-automated-list-of-excel-worksheet-names.html#:~:text=Then%20in%20cell%20B2%20enter,order%20as%20your%20worksheet%20tabs.

Comment: Thanks, @TomSharpe, I reckon it is possible to refer to the whole range of sheets, e.g. Start!A1:Stop!A1 without knowing the sheet names. My trouble is really how to grab unique values across those sheets ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Retrieve Values Across Worksheets

- This is a basic formula. If there are any issues, let us know.

```
=LET(data,Start:Stop!A1:A1000,
    d,TOCOL(data,1),
    u,UNIQUE(d),
HSTACK(u,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(ur,ROWS(FILTER(d,d=ur))))))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised. `TOCOL` is not listed as being supported for 3D references. **ALSO** your formula seems to handle full column references with number of cells exceeding `2^20`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Maybe it's still a *Beta Channel* thing at the moment.

Comment: I'm not a beta channel subscriber.

Answer (score 4):

***Edit after comment from @P.b.***
Only certain functions can accept 3D References.
If you have Office 365 **and if** the total number of **non-blank** cells being referenced is less than `2^20+1`, then you can use this formula:

```
=LET(
    cols, Start:Stop!A:A,
    col, TOCOL(cols, 1),
    UNIQUE(col)
)
```

- cols: all of the sheet ColA data as a multicolumn array
- col: cols converted to a single column with blank cells removed
- `UNIQUE`

Comment: Very educational. I figured it out by trial and error. Didn't know the details behind it.

Comment: Tocol(cols,1) would already filter out blanks. (Untested)

Comment: @P.b Thanks. I missed that argument.

Comment: `TOCOL` without the 1-parameter would have converted all blanks to zeros and `FILTER` just came too late. `FILTER` will fail if there is an error value. `UNIQUE` behaves the same as `TOCOL` except that it removes duplicates, even error duplicates. The issue with `TOCOL` and `UNIQUE` is that they do not get rid off cells containing nothing e.g. `=""` or `'` or these being copied as values etc. That is where `FILTER` steps in: `... TOCOL(cols,3),f,FILTER(col,col<>""),UNIQUE(f))` or `... TOCOL(cols,2),f,FILTER(col,col<>""),UNIQUE(f))` or even `... TOCOL(cols,3),u,UNIQUE(col),FILTER(u,u<>""))`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes, I realized that and edited my answer after P.b. posted a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(v,TOCOL(Start:Stop!A:A,1),
     u,UNIQUE(v),
HSTACK(u,MMULT(N(TOROW(v)=u),SEQUENCE(ROWS(v),,,0))))
```

Basically the same as VBasic2008's answer, however the sum uses MMULT instead of BYROW LAMBDA.

[image]